# Adding The Date and Time to the File name

Tags: java, date, printing, time, writer

Hello I am trying to add the date and time to a file name in JAVA. I can get the date and time printed within the file, which I also want done, but when I place the toString in the FileWriter I get a Null Pointer.

```
package com.mkyong;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    public class Simplex {

        private static PrintWriter outFile;

        //Main Method
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



            // Instantiate a Date object
             Date date = new Date();

             // display time and date using toString()
             outFile.println(date.toString());
             outFile.println();
            //creates the new file to be saved


            outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("simplex" + (date.toString()) + ".txt"));
```

Answer (score 10):

If using java 8

```
DateTimeFormatter timeStampPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        System.out.println(timeStampPattern.format(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Comment: I suggest always passing a `ZoneId` object to the `now()` method. If omitted, the JVM‘s current default time zone is applied. That default can vary. Better to specify explicitly the expected/desired zone.

Answer (score 5):

The line `outFile = new PrintWriter(..)` should occur before first usage of outFile.

Basically you are using outFile before its initialized.

Comment: Ah Thank you. But when I reorder it, the compiler still does not like this line:

    outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("simplex" +(date.toString()) + ".txt"));

Comment: Try putting that line just after the date=new Date() statement

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you to use `YYYY-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss` formatting pattern in file name that allows you to sort out files in a more convinient way. Take a look at `SimpleDateFormat` class.

```
    ...
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");
    outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("simplex_" + formatter.format(date) + ".txt"))
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
String formatedDateTime = current.format(format);
outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("simplex" + formatedDateTime  + ".txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// display time and date using toString()
outFile.println(date.toString());
```

With the code, You use `outFile` before initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Just save it in a variable. You should use the new Date(long) constructor, btw.

```
public class Simplex {

    private static PrintWriter outFile;

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        // Instantiate a Date object
         Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
         String dateString = date.toString();


        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("simplex" + dateString + ".txt"));


         outFile.println(dateString);
         outFile.println();
        //creates the new file to be saved
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that outFile is declared as a static, but never initialized until after you already used it.

You need to first initialize/instantiate outFile first before actually using it:

```
 private static PrintWriter outFile;

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Instantiate a Date object
         Date date = new Date();

        //creates the new file to be saved
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("simplex" + (date.toString()) + .txt"));
        // display time and date using toString()
         outFile.println(date.toString());
         outFile.println();
```

Although I'm not entirely sure why you are even creating outFile as a static object, and not just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned snippet can be used

```
 String logFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'.txt'").format(new Date());

 logFileName = "loggerFile_" + logFileName;
```